# Google Cloud Storage IsLive optional value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Heyo,
I'm using Google Cloud Storage, in a C++ program, via REST/JSON API.

Buckets have [lifecycle rules](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), one of which is a boolean isLive, that specifies whether the lifecycle rule applies to live or archived objects.

But the boolean is optional. So, if the bool is not specified in the rule, does the rule apply to:

- Live only: unspecified defaults to live versions only
- Both live and archived: unspecified means no differentiating

I need to know whether to use an optional boolean/three-value boolean, or a regular boolean.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Lifecycle Conditions in general (including `Age`, `IsLive`, etc.), if there is no value for that condition specified in the rule, then the rule does not filter/differentiate at all based on that condition.

In particular, if you do not specify a value for `IsLive`, the Lifecycle rule will match both live and archived objects. Similarly, if you specify no `Age`, it will not "filter out" any objects based on their creation time.

**Update**: the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#conditions) has been updated to make this more clear:

> All conditions are optional, but at least one condition is required.
>   If a condition is omitted, the lifecycle rule does not filter based on
>   that condition. For example, if Age is omitted, no objects are
>   filtered based on their age.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It's only IsLive boolean that's puzzling in this way, because boolean is traditionally two-state, so to represent this I'd need a three-state boolean. For Age unspecified I could use `-1`, date `""`, etc, only optional boolean doesn't store so simply.